# Wordnet selectional restrictions in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

Is there a way to capture WordNet selectional restrictions (such as +animate, +human, etc.) from synsets through NLTK?
Or is there any other way of providing semantic information about synset? The closest I could get to it were hypernym relations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what is your "selectional restrictions" or i would call it semantic features, because in classic semantics, there exists a world of `concepts` and to compare between concepts we have to find

- **discriminating features** (i.e. features of the concepts that are used to distinguish them from each other) and
- **similarity features** (i.e. features of the concepts similar and highlights the need to differentiate them)

For example:

```
Man is [+HUMAN], [+MALE], [+ADULT]
Woman is [+HUMAN], [-MALE], [+ADULT]

[+HUMAN] and [+ADULT] = similarity features
[+-MALE] is the discrimating features
```

The common problem of traditional semantics and applying this theory in computational semantics is the question of

> "Is there a specific list of features that we can use to compare any
>
> "If so, what are the features on this list?"
>   concepts?"

(see www.acl.ldc.upenn.edu/E/E91/E91-1034.pdf‎ for more details)

Getting back to WordNet, I can suggest 2 methods to resolve the "selection restrictions"

First, **Check the hypernyms for discriminating features**, but first you must decide what is the discriminating features. To differentiate an animal from humans, let's take the discriminating features as [+-human] and [+-animal].

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

# Concepts to compare
dog_sense = wn.synsets('dog')[0] # It's http://goo.gl/b9sg9X
jb_sense = wn.synsets('James_Baldwin')[0] # It's http://goo.gl/CQQIG9

# To access the hypernym_paths()[0]
# It's weird for that hypernym_paths gives a list of list rather than a list, nevertheless it works.
dog_hypernyms = dog_sense.hypernym_paths()[0]
jb_hypernyms = jb_sense.hypernym_paths()[0]


# Discriminating features in terms of concepts in WordNet
human = wn.synset('person.n.01') # i.e. [+human]
animal = wn.synset('animal.n.01') # i.e. [+animal]

try:
  assert human in jb_hypernyms and animal not in jb_hypernyms
  print "James Baldwin is human"
except:
  print "James Baldwin is not human"

try:
  assert human in dog_hypernyms and animal not in dog_hypernyms
  print "Dog is an animal"
except:
  print "Dog is not an animal"
```

Second, **Check for similarity measures as @Jacob had suggested.**

```
dog_sense = wn.synsets('dog')[0] # It's http://goo.gl/b9sg9X
jb_sense = wn.synsets('James_Baldwin')[0] # It's http://goo.gl/CQQIG9

# Features to check against whether the 'dubious' concept is a human or an animal
human = wn.synset('person.n.01') # i.e. [+human]
animal = wn.synset('animal.n.01') # i.e. [+animal]

if dog_sense.wup_similarity(animal) > dog_sense.wup_similarity(human):
  print "Dog is more of an animal than human"
elif dog_sense.wup_similarity(animal) < dog_sense.wup_similarity(human):
  print "Dog is more of a human than animal"
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I realized a while ago I couldn't find the similarity/discriminating features in WordNet due to the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using some of the similarity functions with handpicked synsets, and use that to filter. But it's essentially the same as following the hypernym tree - afaik all the wordnet similarity functions use hypernym distance in their calculations. Also, there's a lot of optional attributes of a synset that might be worth exploring, but their presence can be very inconsistent.